# List containing Dictionary Containing List

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, dictionary

**Question**

I need a data structure like the above in C# but I am having problems accessing the contents, I have seen that I can do this in C++ how is the same done in c#?

```
List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>> data = 
new List<Dictionary<string, List<int>>>(5);
```

when i do Data[0] i get an error stating index out of bounds..

Can anyone point me as to how I can do this. or what I am doing wrong ?

**Addendum:**

->*What im trying to do*

I am basically creating a data structure which keeps a plan of the month.
So a List of the 5 weeks each containing->
a Dictionary of activities, where the value for each activity is a ->
list of 7 integers representing the hours spent each day of the week on that activity.

I have got that I need to add blank entries.
Additional Question is like this.

->*Query*

Right now I will have to Add 5 blank dictionaries to the list.
and a list of 7 integers(initialized to zero) in each Key of the dictionary representing each days time consumed.

Is there a way to initialize 5 blank dictionaries in the list and same inside, without manually creating new dictionaries and adding them. 
With c++ i believe that you can do this and even enter the value to which you want to initialize each entry to be, so..

A statement like

```
Vector<int> *vec = new Vector<int>(5,0);
```

Initialized the vec with 5 entries each being 0. Can I do the same in c# ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 11):

This has nothing to do with the list being a complex type. You'll get the same thing with this:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(5);
string x = list[0]; // This will fail too
```

The [`List<T>(int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z.aspx) constructor creates a list with the given *capacity* (i.e. the array backing it will have an initial size of 5, assuming it doesn't decide that's just too small to be useful). It still has a *size* of 0.

You still need to add elements to the list before you can access them.

EDIT: There's no constructor to "fill" a list with a given set of values. With LINQ you could write:

```
List<string> list = Enumerable.Repeat("foo", 5).ToList();
```

... but you *wouldn't* want to do that for your dictionary one, as otherwise you'll end up with 5 references to the same dictionary. You could use:

```
var list = Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
                     .Select(x => new Dictionary<string, List<int>>())
                     .ToList();
```

Note that each *dictionary* here is empty though.

Personally I'd *probably* just create the list and fill it with a for loop though...

Comment: Thanks, Can you please help me with the added query as edited in the post.I understand that it might not be possible, why has c# not given this feature then ? any insights? :)

Comment: @KshitijBanerjee: C# is a language. You're really asking why the BCL doesn't provide this facility. Will edit.

Comment: Yes, I have done the for loop for now. Just a curious thought. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have initialized the List with a default size of 5, but the list is still empty, thus when you attempt to access index 0 in the data object, it is out of bounds, because the current amount of items in the list is 0, thus there is no objects to access.

if you add a new item to data, with data.Add(...) you can access the object at the first index with data[0]

Comment: "default size" is a confusing term to use here. The *size* is still 0; the *capacity* is 5.